# Flink AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks getCurrentWatermark is never called

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, sliding-window

I'm trying to do a simple Sliding Window aggregation based on a Kafka source.

The events on Kafka all contain a timestamp element and are in ascending order. I've tried using different Periodic Watermarkers (ascending, bounded and a custom one to more easily debug what was going on internally). I can tell that the `extractTimestamp` method is always being called, but the `getCurrentWatermark` method is never called.

I've set the `autoWatermarkInterval` to even 1ms and even then, the watermark for each subtask is never updated. I've verified this by using the Flink UI and looking at the metric available.

I've read quite a few similar questions around this topic on SO and most were about the window never emitting due to several reasons. I haven't been able to identify a reason why it would never advance the watermark.

I've also confirmed that no data is being side outputted as late data.

The stream in it's most basic form:

```scala
      val rfq = kafkaDataStream
        .assignAscendingTimestamps(_.timestamp.toEpochMilli)
        .keyBy("id")

      val lateTag = new OutputTag[RFQ]("late") {}

      val predictions: DataStream[RFQPrediction] = rfq
        .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(5,3))
        .sideOutputLateData(lateTag)
        .aggregate(new PricePredictionsAggregate)
        .name("windowed-predictions")
```

I've verified that it works fine with an `AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks`.

What could be the cause of the `getCurrentWatermark` method to never get called, even though the interval is set to 1ms?

The test data that I'm feeding through uses a limited list of ids for which events are continually being generated with an ever-increasing timestamp.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: And you've configured the workflow to use event time, right?

Comment: Most definitely, I've set `env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)`.

Comment: All looks good, so it's not easy to see the root cause. The only plausible way is that your source is closed very quickly. Is your data actually flowing from Kafka? Which serializer are you using? Are you using `endOfStream`?

Comment: For how long is this streaming job running?

Comment: The data simulator that I've used to test continuously emits items for the id that the stream is keyed by. I've run it for at least 10 minutes. The timestamps are 'randomly' generated with an ever-increasing timestamp. Given that I've even tried setting the window size to 5ms and there are only 20 unique IDs to loop through, there should definitely have been a watermark set and even more than 1 window closed.

I am not using `endOfStream`. I can confirm that the events are being added to the window. The serializer from Kafka is using `KafkaDeserializationSchema`